# Different version of file in Mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have 2 servers with same cloned Mercurial repo but with different config lines in some files in this repo. How can I control this files via Mercurial but haven't problem when pull/puss between servers?

Answer (score 1):

You should rather have under version control:

- one config file **template**
- two config file **values** (one per environment)
- one script able to take the config file template and fill it with the right values depending on the environment.

That way, no problem during pull/push.

Comment: This question is very similar to the question I posted last night in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789875/how-can-i-have-two-streams-of-development-branches-track-each-other-while-r // the answers received so far are equally unsatisfactory. // In my post I explain how a more satisfactory solution was available in CVS.  I hope that the DVCSes can offer something almost as good.

Comment: By the way, rather than going all the way to a template, I often have ~/.config.system1 and ~/.config.system2, and have the script create a symlink from ~/.config -> ~/.config.system1 as appropriate.  // Doesn't help if there are only a few differences, which are replicated, but helps if they are significantly different. // However, I would still prefer to find a solution that handles this better, such as I did in CVS.